# Setting user interface type doesn't work while finding user

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, types, typegoose

setting type is not working. It shows

> Type '(Document<string, BeAnObject, any> & UserSchema &
> IObjectWithTypegooseFunction & { _id: string; })[]' is missing the
> following properties from type 'IUserInput': username, email,
> password, confirmPassword, and 59 more.

```
export interface IUserInput extends DocumentType<UserSchema> {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  confirmPassword: string;
  _id: string;
  avatar: string;
  salt: string;
  likes: typeof Like[];
  token: string;
  role: number;
  comparePassword: (password: string, salt: string) => boolean;
}

export const GetUser = async (
  identifyer: IUserInput["username"] | IUserInput["email"],
  properties: string,
) => {
  const user: IUserInput = await User.find( // user returns error here
    {
      $or: [{ email: identifyer }, { username: identifyer }],
    },
    `${properties}`,
  );

  return user;
};
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8yH2.png

silly error but I'm stuck
I'm using typegoose

Comment: Adding your code to the question other than in an image would help more.

Can we see the IUserInput interface. Seems the return type of your find is not the same as IUserInput

Comment: also can you explain how to deal with this nasty errors as they pop everywhere. And it's hard to know and solve.

Comment: I think your issue may be that you use `find`, which returns a array but expect a single document `IUserInput`, maybe try `IUserInput[]` or use `findOne`

Comment: that first solution works. thank you.